# Should the "samsung-gt-i9000" tag be a synonym of the "samsung-galaxy-s" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[samsung-gt-i9000](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-gt-i9000) and [samsung-galaxy-s](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s) are about the same device. The full name of the device is: Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000. So I would suggest it as a synonym, but I don't have the reputation yet.

If someone with > 2500 reputation agrees, please suggest the synonym. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was that the name Galaxy S actually refers to a series of 9+ devices, but we should probably make the synonym you suggest and create `samsung-galaxy-s-series` is there's a need for it.

I've merged and synonymized the tags.